# Class Def Python Try/Except

Tags: python, python-2.7, funciones, selenium

Ando buscando alguien que me ayude con `funciones` y `clases` de python. Siempre había trabajado con funciones pero nunca con funciones dentro de funciones. Cuando quería correr el programa no realizaba ninguna acción de mis funciones hasta que cambie los `def` por `class` como pueden ver en el código.
Estoy buscando cambiar esto para que yo pueda mandar los parámetros en el `def main` directamente que quiero que tomen mis variables dentro de las funciones. Para ser mas claro dejo par del código de como me gustaría que sea. Necesito que sea de esta forma ya que yo trabajo con bases de datos que provienen de otro archivo y ya tengo todo armada mi base de datos de la cual saco los parametros desde el `def mail()`

Saludos

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Martin/Desktop/chromedriver')
timeout = 30
driver.get("https://onevideo.aol.com/#/")


def main():
    login()
    clone()
    Name()
    Rate()
    Floor()
    Download()


class login():
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.ng-valid:nth-child(1)"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")

    username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.ng-valid:nth-child(1)")
    username.send_keys("martinbouhier")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn:nth-child(2)").click()
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.group-field-block:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(2)"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")

    password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.group-field-block:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(2)")
    password.send_keys("pass")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".button").click()
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h1.ng-scope > span:nth-child(1)')))


class clone():
#Clonar
    url = driver.get("https://onevideo.aol.com/#/inventorysources")
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ngRow:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(9) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > adap-options-menu:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(2)"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)

    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.ngRow:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(9) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > adap-options-menu:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(2)').click()
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ngRow:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(9) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > adap-options-menu:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(2)"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)

    except TimeoutException:
        print ("Timed out waiting for page to load")    
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.open > ul:nth-child(5) > li:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)').click()
```

Necesito que sea algo parecido a esto, donde trabajo todos los datos de mi base de dataos en el run():

```
def run(d):
    NewTag("url")
    Device = str(d.get("Li_platform")) #Mobile Web 
    Inicio_Li_Platform = ('//*[@id="platform_listbox"]/li[')
    Final_Li_Platform = (']')
    Platform(Inicio_Li_Platform+""+Device+""+Final_Li_Platform)
    NameTag(d.get("TagName"))
    Floor_Rate(d.get("Floor_price"))
    Save_Tag('save')
    Inicio_Li_Publisher = ('//*[@id="publisher_listbox"]/li[')
    Final_Li_Publisher = (']')
    Publisher = str(d.get("Li_Publisher")) #Publisher Altitude
    Publisher_Li(Inicio_Li_Publisher+""+Publisher+""+Final_Li_Publisher)
    Tag_Rate_and_Save(d.get("Tag_Rate"))
    time.sleep(2)


def main():
    login("martin", "pass")
    tags = (nametags)

    for tag in (tag.strip() for tag in tags.split(",")):
        d = (Inventory_data.get("Inventario_datos")).get(tag, None)
        if d:
            run(d)
        else:
            print('Error: Clave "{}" no encontrada.'.format(tag))
    driver.close()


def login(email, passwd):
        url = "url/login/"
        email_find = '//*[@id="form_username"]'
        passwd_find = '//*[@id="form_password"]'
        boton_find = '//*[@id="login_submit"]'
        driver.get(url)
        user = driver.find_element_by_xpath(email_find)
        user.send_keys(email)
        password = driver.find_element_by_xpath(passwd_find)
        password.send_keys(passwd)
        boton_find = driver.find_element_by_xpath(boton_find).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Martín estas confundiendo `class` con `def`. La palabra `class` se usa para definir clases para una programación orientada a objetos ([POO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_orientada_a_objetos)) no hay que meter codigo como si fuese una función.
Una clase para que te des una idea es una entidad que sirve para definir un objeto como puede ser persona:

```
class Persona:
    """Simple clase de ejemplo"""
    edad = 34
    def saludar_a_alguien(self, nombre):
        return "hola {}".format(nombre)

    def saludar(self):
        return 'hola mundo'

eduardo = Persona()
print(eduardo.saludar())
```

Recomiendo que leas la documentación oficial de python sobre [clases](http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/3/classes.html)
Pero es una paradigma de programación que va más allá de python.

Comment: Entiendo lo que escribis y entiendo la diferencia entre ambas pero cuando pongo def en vez de class no me ejecuta las funciones. No me da ningun error pero no hace nada el programa, Solo abre el selenium!